# How to earn the Documentation Pioneer badge?

Tags: support, documentation, badges

It says that you have to have 3+ substantive contribution during the first month of 
Documentation to earn the Documentation Pioneer Badge.

[image]

I find "substantive" to be tricky word. What does it mean here? How do I earn the badge?

Comment: Probably edits of more than a certain number of characters, like 10 or something. Shouldn't be too hard to get if roughly 30% of people who've participated in Documentation have earned it in the first week.

Comment: Yet another case of [using words that are too big](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269289/our-words-are-too-complicated-lets-make-them-simpler)?

Comment: @BoltClock "having a firm basis in reality and therefore important, meaningful, or considerable" is the definition of substantive. So now we are to believe that the system is sentient and is weighing the contributions of each user itself before awarding the badges? Or, maybe 'substantive' without more detail was just a poor choice.

Comment: @TylerH: No, we're just using big words for the sake of sounding professional and needlessly confusing readers as a result.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, I thought you were referring that MSE post satirically for some reason.

Comment: I think it just means 3 helpful edits. Because useless, 1 word edits will be rejected by your reviewing peers

Comment: @svarog "*Because useless, 1 word edits will be rejected by your reviewing peers*". Good one, cracked me up:D

Comment: dammit I forgot to do this badge; my life is over

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get the Documentation Pioneer badge today because I had three edits in 3 Documentation Topics on the first month of release of Documentation Beta. I do not know if there are other substantive ways to get the badge.

Comment: I got the badge simultaneously with an upvote to an example I wrote, so I *suppose* your changes have to be subsequently upvoted to get the badge.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Substantive contributions in the Documentation could mean many things. It could mean edits, topic creation, etc. Of course you always need positive feedback from others before they could be considered to be worth something.

Answer (score 12):

This is just poor word choice. Instead of "**substantive**", they meant to say "***substantial***". The words look very similar, but they have slightly different (if also somewhat overlapping) meanings.

Substantive is defined by Random House Dictionary as:

> 1. having a firm basis in reality and therefore important, meaningful, or considerable.
>   2. having a separate and independent existence.

"Important" and "meaningful" are certainly two guidelines we're shooting for here when assessing candidates for the badge, but according to this definition, these are predicated upon "having a firm basis in reality". I'm not sure how that applies in this instance. In a strictly literal sense, all contributions that are accepted to Documentation have a firm basis in reality; in a more metaphysical sense, it loses all meaning. The second definition obviously doesn't apply at all. It is very unclear how a machine could ever determine that your contribution(s) are substantive or "meaningful". So using the word "substantive" here maybe kinda works, if you already know what it is trying to say, but isn't very clear, especially to a non-native speaker that might have to look up the definition of the word.

Substantive also has a specific meaning in law, where it is the opposite of "procedural". If you are exonerated from a crime because the rules of evidence were not followed, that's a procedural matter. If you were exonerated because you didn't murder the victim, then that's a substantive matter. This interpretation *might* be valid in this case, except that (1) it is far too technical to be expected to be widely understood, and (2) the algorithm doesn't actually distinguish between substantive and procedural edits in this context. Reorganizing the existing content would be a procedural contribution, not a substantive one in this sense, but the system would still count that as sufficient for earning the badge, assuming you did a non-trivial amount of it.

On the other hand, substantial is defined as:

> 1. of ample or considerable amount, quantity, size, etc.
>   [...]
>   6. of real worth, value, or effect

That's the meaning we're actually looking for here. You are a candidate for the badge if you've made an ample, considerable, and valuable contribution to Documentation that provides some real worth or value to the site. Something that is substantial has some actual bulk to it—it is more than just fluff. In other words, you've made a *non-trivial* contribution. This is rather easy to determine algorithmically, based on the actual size of your contribution(s).

The word "**significant**" would also be a satisfactory alternative. I'm not sure if that would be clearer to a non-native speaker.

Comment: I'm getting a strong feeling of deja vu -- I'm pretty sure the substantive/substantial confusion has been noted and corrected before in some other Stack Exchange feature.  Searching for _substantive_ on both MSO and MSE just finds more examples of the mistake.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom you mean there's a substantive amount of similar cases?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Did you do a substative amount of searching?